# Registrar datos en SQL llegado el día de una fecha

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, nodejs

Cuento con una API en Node JS, la cual interactua con una base de datos y otro equipo.

Busco alguna erramienta que me permita actualizar datos en la base de datos a partir de una fecha.

En la base de datos cuento con una tabla llamada `clients`, la cual tiene una `created_invoice` (de tipo int). Necesito que cuando llegue el día de pago se registre una factura en otra tabla (`invoices`), de forma automática.

No se si tengo que hacerlo con un procedimiento almacenado o con un trigger; de ser asi, ¿Cómo hago que se ejecute automáticamente llegada la fecha de vencimiento?.

Al mismo tiempo requiero que al crearse el registro en la tabla `invoices` la API pueda enviar un "aviso" (por asi decirlo) al equipo, para que se realice alguna tarea especifica.

Comment: Bueno.. tenes que hacer varias cosas.. ninguna de las que dijiste.. o si.. Necesitas el SP.. para hacer lo que queres.. pero tambien necesitas una tarea croneada en tu servidor que se ejecute cada X cantidad de tiempo y haga ejecutar ese SP.. un trigger, no tiene nada que ver... y lo otro que quieres.. requiere que tu db de alguna forma envie el aviso (no tu api, la api no hace nada por si sola, solo cuando la llaman).. en este punto, tal vez si te sirva un trigger sobre esa tabla... Igual, esta es mi opinion, y tal vez otro opine de otra forma....

Comment: Si tienes que hacer tantas cosas, yo me decantaría por una tarea programada en el servidor, como dice @gbianchi. En esa tarea buscas que registros están en la condición de ser facturados y lanzas cuantos procesos necesites.

Comment: ¿Qué sistema operativo estás usando?

Comment: Utilizó Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para este tipo de tareas te recomiendo hacer uso de la biblioteca 'node-cron'.

```
npm install --save node-cron
```

Con ella solo debes especificar (en este caso) que todos los días a una determinada hora se ejecute una consulta a tu base de datos en la tabla 'clients' quienes deben pagar ese día en cuestión y genere el registro que requieras en 'invoices'.

```
const cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('0 0 * * *', () => {
    tarea1();
    tarea2();
    tarea3();
});
```

Con el código mostrado previamente, todos los días a las 00:00 se ejecutarán las tareas 'tarea1', 'tarea2' y 'tarea3'.

Te dejo en enlace a la página de 'node-cron' disponible en 'npm' [Enlace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron)

Comment: Muchas gracias, justamente eso utilice para resolver mi situación.